# Relating population-level AUC (Somers's $D_{xy}$) to a mean shift

Tags: normal-distribution, roc, auc, somers-d

Say we have group $0$ distributed as $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and group $1$ distributed as $N(\mu+\delta, \sigma^2)$. We then use the Gaussian-distributed variables to predict group membership. It seems like we should have some way to relate $\delta\big/\sigma^2$ to the area under the receiver-operator characteristic curve, and a simulation supports this idea.

```r
library(pROC)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2024)
N <- 100000#0 # A million took longer than I wanted
deltas <- seq(-4, 4, 0.1)
aucs <- rep(NA, length(deltas))
for (i in 1:length(deltas)){
  
  # Standardize variance to 1
  #
  x0 <- rnorm(N, 0, 1)
  x1 <- rnorm(N, 0 + deltas[i], 1)
  
  y0 <- rep(0, N)
  y1 <- rep(1, N)
  x <- c(x0, x1)
  y <- c(y0, y1)
  r <- pROC::roc(y, x, direction = "<")
  aucs[i] <- r$auc
  print(paste(
    i/length(deltas)*100,
    "% complete",
    sep = ""
  ))
}
d <- data.frame(
  Delta = abs(deltas),
  ROCAUC = aucs
)
ggplot(d, aes(y = Delta, x = ROCAUC)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: delta vs ROCAUC]

Mathematically, what is this relationship, and how specific is it to Gaussians?

Answer (score 0):

The textbook definition of Somers' D is like a correlation coefficient with range [-1,1], and is very similar to Kendall's tau.  So, perhaps based on the roc function you called, Somer's D from the roc function only has range [0,1] -- like what is shown on the x-axis. In this case, a Somer's D of 0.5 is really like zero correlation, where $\delta=0$.  At $\delta=0$, the simulated x-y pairs would merely be noise, hence zero correlation or 0.5 on your plot.

You only showed a plot for N=10,000.  So more curves could be generated.  However, is what you did really ground-breaking, and would it make a contribution to the literature?  No, not really.